# canvas imageDraw() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I want to get image data using toDataURL().but my Imagedraw() method is not working.

```
    var video = document.getElementById('media-video');
            var videoCurrentTime = document.getElementById('media-video').currentTime;
            var canvasWidth = $('video').width();
            var canvasHeight = $('video').height();
            var c = $('body').append($('<canvas>',{id: 'myCanvas', width:canvasWidth, height:canvasHeight}));

    var ctx;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        c = document.getElementById('myCanvas');                        
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");            
    });
    c.onload=function(){
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0,canvasWidth , canvasHeight);
    }  
    imageData = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1.0);

    window.open(imageData, "toDataURL() image", "width=600, height=200");
}
```

I could see a blank canvas returned in imageData.

Comment: I've tried it providing static values

Comment: the above code is in iframe. Does  it has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Becouse `c.onload=` is acyns. You most get toDataURL after onload.

```
c.onload=function(){
    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0,canvasWidth , canvasHeight);
    imageData = this.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1.0);
  window.open(imageData, "toDataURL() image", "width=600, height=200");
}
```

Comment: didn't work. $(document).ready(function(){       
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0,canvasWidth , canvasHeight);
        } ); imageData = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1.0);                                                                                        now the problem is toDataURL() code

Comment: c.onload you have toDataURL() ?